# Clockpicker Jquery Plugin Reading Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add the clock picker Jquery plugin to my website. I build it first in the extern file, then I migrate the code into my website html, but doesn't work.

I already try to fix the problem with the console, and I see an error 404 with the link, ../css/style.css, but the problem I didn't add any link about a file "style.css".

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap - CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/reservation.css">




<!-- FontAwesome CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--Font-->
```

```
<!-- Jquery JS & CSS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


<!-- Time-Picker CSS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/datetimepicker/clockpicker.css">

<!-- Time-Picker JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/clockpicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/mesfonctions.js"></script>

<title> Réservation - Café Restaurant du Chemin de Fer</title>
```

I expect that the trouble doesn't come from my html file actually. Can have a problem with the clocktimer.js (the plugin I mean?)

Comment: Please share snippet or jsfiddle.net

Comment: @chandershekhar here there is, hope my code is a good one..I'm french speaker, and beginn with programming since 4 months... Thx for support :)

https://jsfiddle.net/BrySch/m2ro1pky/